# Der Teil in Der Nachteil and der Vorteil?

Tags: etymology

Is **der Teil** (a part) the root of **der Nachteil** (disadvantage) and **der Vorteil** (advantage)?

If so, have you got other examples of compound words that use *nach* and *vor* to express two opposed things.

Comment: Hast Du versucht mit Hilfe eines Wörterbuchs die Frage selbst zu beantworten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To question 1:

Yes, in both cases the word *Teil* is a component, see [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Nachteil#et-1).

To question 2:

Difficult to recognize, what you are asking; would *Vorspeise* / *Nachspeise* or *Vorhut* / *Nachhut* qualify? The problem is, that *vor*/*nach* are typically simply a sort of ordering in time or space, which seldom results in real opposites. The closest match I can think of is *Vorsicht* vs. *Nachsehen*.

Comment: The examples totally answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Mit einem kleinen Script kann man in seinen digitalen Wörterbüchern (bei mir utf-german) nach Übereinstimmungen suchen:

```
#!/bin/bash
v=($(grep Vor utf-german) ); n=($(grep Nach utf-german) )
for vw in ${v[*]}; do for nw in ${n[*]}; 
do
  test ${vw:3} = ${nw:4} && echo $vw" "$nw; 
done; done
```

Die Liste musste ich dann von langweiligen Mehrzahlfällen u.ä. befreien und prüfen, ob es sich tatsächlich um Gegensätze handelt, was wegen Mehrdeutigkeiten und seltenen Ausdrücken in Fachsprachen nicht immer einfach ist. Ein *Vortrag* kann eine Rede sein, es gibt aber auch den *Vortrag* bei einem Konto im Rechnungswesen. Für beide ist mir Nachtrag als Gegenteil nicht bekannt. Ein P.S. in einem Brief kann man aber als Nachtrag bezeichnen. Vorschub ist ein Begriff im Ingenieurswesen, ob die auch Nachschub kennen, weiß ich nicht - im Militär gibt es Nachschub aber m.W. keinen Vorschub.

```
Vorarbeit Nacharbeit
Vorbau Nachbau
Vorbedingung Nachbedingung
Vorbereitung Nachbereitung
Vorgeschmack Nachgeschmack
Vorhinein Nachhinein
Vorkauf Nachkauf
Vorlauf Nachlauf
Vorleben Nachleben
Vormittag Nachmittag
Vorname Nachname
Vorprüfung Nachprüfung
Vorsaison Nachsaison
Vorschau Nachschau
Vorschuss Nachschuss
Vorsilbe Nachsilbe
Vorspeise Nachspeise
Vorteil Nachteil
Voruntersuchung Nachuntersuchung
Vorwahlen Nachwahlen
Vorwort Nachwort
```

Vorsicht/Nachsicht würde ich dagegen ausgerechnet nicht gelten lassen. Das eine ist Aufmerksamkeit, das andere Gnade.

Dass die Begriffe örtlich oder zeitlich in gegenteilige Richtung liegen macht sie gerade zum Gegenteil. Was sonst, wenn nicht Nachsaison, sollte etwa das Gegenteil von Vorsaison sein?

Und ja, Teil ist der Stamm der Wörter Vorteil und Nachteil.